# how do i align a textbox to the center of the screen in HTML?

Tags: php, html, css

OK, I'm creating a simple login page. this is what I have so far;

```
<?php
$user = $_POST["username"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];
$validated = false;
session_start();
if($user!=""&&$pass!="")
{

    if($user=="Kenny"&&$pass=="Hereford")
        $validated = true;
    if($validated)
    {
        $_SESSION['BTECPage'] = "OK";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
        header('Location: protected.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['BTECPage'] = "";
        echo "Invalid username or password.";
    }
}
else $_SESSION['BTECPage'] = "";
?>

<html>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Login Page</h1>
<p align="center">Please enter your username and password:</p>
    <form action="BTECLoginPage.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">Username: </td>
            <td align="center"><input size=\"20\"
                       type="text" size="20" maxlength="15"
                       name="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td
                align="center">Password: </td>
            <td align="center"><input size=\"20\"
                       type="password" size="20"
                       maxlength="15" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td colspan="2"
                align="center"><input type="submit"
                                    value="Login"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the textboxes to align to the center correctly? I know of the align feature but where do i place it?

I'm still kinda new to this so sorry if this is a noob question

Comment: <table align="center"> its work for me try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do much simpler aligning using CSS but you probably want to use HTML's parameters.

You can align the table by simply adding `align="center"` as you have previously done on other tags.

Now that the form is aligned, the submit button is weirdly aligned because you have an additional `<td>` that you do not need. Removing that would help and the submit button will also be in the center.

Code for the table:

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Username: </td>
        <td align="center"><input size=\"20\"
                   type="text" size="20" maxlength="15"
                   name="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td
            align="center">Password: </td>
        <td align="center"><input size=\"20\"
                   type="password" size="20"
                   maxlength="15" name="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"
            align="center"><input type="submit"
                                value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to align it into center try this one `<table style="width:200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border:1px solid #ddd; padding:10px;">`